# Converting tuple into list does not work

Tags: python, list, sqlite, formatting, tuples

I query my SQlite Database with a loop to retrieve data from it.

```
connector = sqlite3.connect("somedb.db")
selecter = connector.cursor()
selecter.execute(''' SELECT somedata FROM somedb''')
for row in selecter:
    l = list(row)
    print (l)
    print (type(l))
```

Then I try do use formatting to append the retrieved data to something else

```
this = detect.that( "{}", pick, summary).format(l)
```

But it comes back with this:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I also tried this

```
s = " ".join(str(row) for row in selecter)
```

for the `l = list(row)` statement but it comes back with the same errormessage and it seems that it converts all my 50 separate selections into one string what I dont want.

However, when I run this

```
print (type(l))
```

or

```
print (type(s))
```

it returns me `list` or `string`as a type. So the converting worked, but the `.format` does not take it because it thinks it is a tuple.

How comes?

Comment: Clearly `detect.that` returns a tuple, not a string.

Comment: I cannot insert a `tuple` there neither.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `detect.that` line to this:

```
this = str(detect.that("{}", pick, summary)).format(1)
```

Comment: That is not working neither. Still the same errormessage

Comment: Fixed it, try it again.

Comment: I did not forget it. I was not at home for several days. I will try it later when I am back at home!

Comment: That does not work neither. Now I get this error: 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)'